# How to work with GO SDK while Azure AD user creation?

Tags: go, azure-ad-b2b

Would like to create Azure AD user from GO SDK programmatically but can't find any related docs. I am new to this platform.

From Azure Portal I know how to create user, but the requirement is do it from GO.

Anyone tried and got the results? Can someone help with sample GO code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **To create user from GO SDK, you can make use of below sample code as mentioned in this** [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=go#request):

```cs
//THE GO SDK IS IN PREVIEW. NON-PRODUCTION USE ONLY

graphClient := msgraphsdk.NewGraphServiceClient(requestAdapter)

requestBody := msgraphsdk.NewUser()
accountEnabled := true
requestBody.SetAccountEnabled(&accountEnabled)
displayName := "User1"
requestBody.SetDisplayName(&displayName)
mailNickname := "test"
requestBody.SetMailNickname(&mailNickname)
userPrincipalName := "user1@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
requestBody.SetUserPrincipalName(&userPrincipalName)
passwordProfile := msgraphsdk.NewPasswordProfile()
requestBody.SetPasswordProfile(passwordProfile)
forceChangePasswordNextSignIn := true
passwordProfile.SetForceChangePasswordNextSignIn(&forceChangePasswordNextSignIn)
password := "*********"
passwordProfile.SetPassword(&password)
result, err := graphClient.Users().Post(requestBody)
```

To know how to integrate GO SDK with Azure Ad you can **refer** below link:

[Install a Microsoft Graph SDK - Microsoft Graph | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdk-installation#install-the-microsoft-graph-go-sdk-preview)

Comment: Thanks but can't I use this for production? What does NON-PRODUCTION ONLY mean?

Comment: This is useless since the MS docs don't show how to create the requestAdapter.